# issue while preview pdf from remoteURL

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, pdfview

i am implementing pdf preview in my `Swift` app so i have decided to use third party library for Preview PDF i am using below library

[Please Check Library Here](https://github.com/uxmstudio/UXMPDFKit)

so first i am download url and store to document directory and than i am displaying it but pdf not previewed below is my code

```
func downloadFileFromURL(url: String)  {

    if let audioUrl = URL(string: url) {

        let documentsDirectoryURL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

        let destinationUrl = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(audioUrl.lastPathComponent)
        print(destinationUrl)


        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: destinationUrl.path) {
            print("The file already exists at path")
            print(destinationUrl)
            let document = try! PDFDocument(filePath: destinationUrl.lastPathComponent, password: "")

            self.collectionView.document = document
        } else {
            URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: audioUrl, completionHandler: { (location, response, error) -> Void in
                guard let location = location, error == nil else { return }
                do {
                    try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: destinationUrl)
                    print(destinationUrl)
                    let document = try! PDFDocument(filePath: destinationUrl.lastPathComponent, password: "")

                    self.collectionView.document = document
                    print("File moved to documents folder")
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }).resume()
        }
    }
}
```

and inside `viewDidLoad()` i am implementing below code

```
downloadFileFromURL(url: "http://housedocs.house.gov/edlabor/AAHCA-BillText-071409.pdf")
```

but still pdf is not previewed can some tell me its the right way to preview pdf with UXMPdf

or suggest me best pdfviewer for `Swift` from which i can load pdf from `URL`

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the full `path` rather than the last path component.

And remove the `!` inside a `do - catch` block.

```
let document = try PDFDocument(filePath: destinationUrl.path, password: "")
```

As the `password` parameter is unused I recommend to use the built-in initializer

```
let document = try PDFDocument(url: destinationUrl)
```

Comment: if i put with url than i am getting error `Incorrect argument label in call (have 'url:', expected 'coder:')`

Comment: It seems that the library hides the `url` initializer. So use the first syntax.

Comment: Did you replace both occurrences of `PDFDocument(filePath:`? Set a breakpoint to check if the document was loaded at all